# Rollup Helper - No Percent Support?

Tags: rolluphelper

Trying to create a new rollup with Rollup Helper and it seems like Percent targets aren't supported. Is that the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ralph you are correct, As of right now percent fields are not supported as a target field for a rollup in Rollup Helper.

We have added this feature to our backlog items and will work towards implementing this into our App.

Comment: Glad to hear it's on the way!